# no output from .NET console app run from psexec

Tags: .net, console, pipe, psexec

I'm having a very strange problem where I run a managed .net console app on a remote server using psexec.  I get this error "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe".

Now I wrote an unmanaged C++ program to output to std::cout, and it works just fine.

Interestingly, if I run cmd.exe remotely, and use the /u (unicode) option, I don't get the error, but I get garbage text streamed back to the console.

Can anyone explain what might be going on here?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, I remotely run a .cmd script, which runs the .net application, redirecting (">") its output to a file.  I then "type" the file in the script, and I now get output back.

I still don't understand why the .net application's console output is getting lost, but this work-around does the job.

Mark

Comment: I didn't actually get it working.  I just had the cmd script I was trying to run, redirect its output to a file. Then "type" the file to stdout.  Strange, but it worked.